# How to set level for log4j in spring boot?

Tags: logging, log4j, spring-boot

I have set log4j level in application.properties file

```
logging.level: DEBUG
logging.level: ERROR
logging.file=${HOME}/application.log
```

but on console i am not getting debug and error information nor in application.log . I am only getting info .

In class i defined logger like this

```
public static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You listed logging.level twice in your application.properties. Remove the second entry for ERROR.

2) Chang line to logging.level.=DEBUG

3) Although it might not make a difference, for 2 entries you are using ":" as the key-value separator and "=" for the last one. Just be consistent.

Comment: Digging up a grave here. But this didn't work for me. What worked was setting logging.level.root=DEBUG
I am using Log4j2